# MS Access SQL with self join produces less results than original table, what does the set of records that aren't present in query represent?

Tags: sql, ms-access

My original table (*File05292019*) has 22,904 records.  I perform a self join on 3 of the fields as shown below and the result is 22,886.  Why is this the case? What do the missing records represent?

```
SELECT File05292019.LastName, File05292019.FirstName, File05292019.SubscriberSocialSecurityNumber
FROM File05292019 
INNER JOIN File05292019 AS File05292019_1 
    ON (File05292019.SubscriberSocialSecurityNumber = File05292019_1.SubscriberSocialSecurityNumber) 
    AND (File05292019.LastName = File05292019_1.LastName) 
    AND (File05292019.FirstName = File05292019_1.FirstName)
GROUP BY File05292019.LastName, File05292019.FirstName, File05292019.SubscriberSocialSecurityNumber;
```

Answer (score 1):

Because of group operator. You should have duplicate records in result set

Check by running this query

```
SELECT File05292019.LastName, File05292019.FirstName, File05292019.SubscriberSocialSecurityNumber
FROM File05292019 
INNER JOIN File05292019 AS File05292019_1 
    ON (File05292019.SubscriberSocialSecurityNumber = File05292019_1.SubscriberSocialSecurityNumber) 
    AND (File05292019.LastName = File05292019_1.LastName) 
    AND (File05292019.FirstName = File05292019_1.FirstName)
```

Answer (score 1):

the presence of group by  suggest  that 
this mean that you have some rows  with the same  values

you  could try uisng

```
  SELECT File05292019.LastName
    , File05292019.FirstName
    , File05292019.SubscriberSocialSecurityNumber
    count(*)
  FROM File05292019 
  GROUP BY File05292019.LastName
    , File05292019.FirstName
    , File05292019.SubscriberSocialSecurityNumber
  HAVING count(*) > 1
```

for find these rows

Answer (score 1):

Couple of possibilities:

1. `NULL` values exist in the `JOIN` fields: *SubscriberSocialSecurityNumber*, *LastName*, and *FirstName*. Because `NULL = NULL` is a `False` statement, joins exclude nulls (non-value entities).
2. Duplicate values in `GROUP BY` fields where the aggregation returns distinct values by grouping. Add the `COUNT(*) As RecordCount` aggregate to see which fields have more than 1 value.

   Possibly subscribers changed their names but retained same SSNs; names and SSNs were incorrectly inputted; or several records use a default status like `999-99-9999`?